# Java method using reflection and matcher

Tags: java, regex, reflection

I need a method that takes 2 parameters:

The template parameter can be :
Hi `${name}`, There's been `${days}` days since you logged in on ${site}.
The object parameter its an object for example: `Site site = new Site("Alex",100,"google");`

If `${ xxx }` is found then i need to replace with the `getMethod` from `Object`

So if we call the method needs to return Hello Alex , There's been 100 days since you logged in on Google.

this is what i have:

```
public static String metodaex2(String template, Object object)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
        InvocationTargetException {

    Class<?> clasa = object.getClass();
    Method[] methodsArray = clasa.getDeclaredMethods();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Object methodReturn = null;
    Set<Object> listObjects = new TreeSet<Object>(new ObjectsComparator());
    for (Method m : methodsArray ){
        //a method that finds a getter
        if (isGetter(m)) {
            //add to the list all get methods
            methodReturn = m.invoke(object);
            listObjects.add(methodReturn);
        }

    }
    String pattern1 = "${";
    String pattern2 = "}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)"
            + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(template);

    while (matcher.find()) {
             System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); /
         matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1));

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But i dont know how to make the actual replacement. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some trails you could use to do such a job.

*Read an object's property value given its name:*

```java
public static Object readProperty(String name, Object object) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    do {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
            return field.get(object);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
    } while (clazz != null);
    return null;
}
```

*Regex matching your pattern, capturing the property name (visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HkucBZxlNOIva8NL)):*

```
\$\{([^}]+)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

*Iterating over matches in Java:*

```java
    String input = "Hi ${name}, There's been ${days} days since you logged in on ${site}.";
    String regex = "\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        // name contains now the property name
        // add the logic here: replace occurrences of "${" + name + "}" by the real value
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but for example:
Hi, your name is ${name}
would return Hi, your Alex is Alex

Comment: @alex1111 You'll simply have to replace in the input string any occurrence of the string `"${" + name + "}"` by the *real* value. See [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (don't forget to escape the first argument using [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))).

Comment: i did this
template = template.replaceAll(matcher.group(1), value.toString());
template = template.replaceAll(regex, value.toString());

but i have the same problem. I dont understand how can i use pattern.split

Comment: @alex1111 `Pattern#quote` must be used, not `Pattern#split`. Only one `replaceAll` should be enough: `template.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("${" + name + "}"), value.toString());`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a templating engine such as [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) which have already solved this problem (and many more).